# what does the elm signature mean in "Program Never Model Msg"?

Tags: elm

I'm just starting on elm and without understanding Haskell and its compiler 
I'm trying to grasp what the signature mean in `Html.program`

```
func: (a -> String) -> String -- this means expects a function and return a string
main: Program Never Model Msg -- What does this mean?
```

Comment: A lot of the concepts and the documentation around Elm assume a learner has read https://guide.elm-lang.org. If you haven't already checked it out, take a moment to read the Elm Architecture and JavaScript interopt sections, since they are most relevant to your question.

Comment: @jmlane I have gone through the guide and I think my question reflects that. If I were to rephrase the question, it would be what does space-delimited Modules means as that doesn't seem to be mentioned. https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/type_aliases.html

Comment: Ah I see. If you feel that's a better representation of your question, you could make that edit. It wasn't clear to me that you had read through the sections I mentioned in the guide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Program`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform#Program) is a type parameterized by three type variables: `flags`, `model`, and `msg`. [`Never`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Basics#Never) is a type that cannot have any value (see the link for a good explanation of what this means and how it differs from the unit type `()`).

`Program Never Model Msg` therefore is the type of a program that doesn't have any flags (`Never`), has a model of type `Model`, and passes messages of type `Msg`.